# WPF Binding to UserControl´s DependencyProperty not working as expected

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have some strange problem with DependecyProperty-binding.
To keep the question simpler i´ve created some dummy-control, that has the same unwanted behaviour

I have a UserControl, that has a DependencyProperty defined in code behind:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TestValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TestValue", typeof(string), typeof(Test), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

public string TestValue
{    
     get { return (string)GetValue(TestValueProperty); }
     set { SetValue(TestValueProperty, value); }
}
```

This property is used in XAML:

```
<Label Content="{Binding TestValue}" />
```

This control should be used in another control like this:

```
<views:Test TestValue="{Binding Settings.Setting123}" />
```

`Settings` is defined in viewmodel as property.

But the content of `Settings.Setting123` is not visible in my usercontrol´s label.

When writing some fixes value instead of the binding it works fine:

```
<views:Test TestValue="Test" />
```

But of course i do not want a fixed value, but the content of the bound object.
Any hint what is going wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Although you haven't shown it in your question, you certainly set the DataContext of the UserControl to itself, (e.g. by `DataContext = this` in its constructor). Remove that, and write the Bindings in the UserControl's XAML with a RelativeSource, as shown in Ed's answer.

Comment: Yes, DataContext in UserControl is like this: DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"

Comment: That's the problem. See my answer on the duplicate question. And probably accept Ed's answer here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't share enough code for anybody to recreate the issue, but reading between the lines, I'm guessing that `Label` is in your `UserControl` XAML. If `TestValue` is a property of your `UserControl`, this will probably work:

```
<Label Content="{Binding TestValue, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
```

One thing you did right: Your UserControl constructor must always set `DataContext = this;`. No exceptions.

Comment: Yep, that pretty much did the job. Thanks for helping!